# How to enable Wifi on an AVD

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, android-emulator

How can I enable WiFi on an AVD? I am emulating the Android version 2.3.3 API 10 and when I click WiFi in the phone settings menu it just says 'error'.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the StackOverflow question [Enabling Wifi on Android Emulator](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator), but is also on topic here for Android Virtual Device users.

Comment: Some useful answers here :
[How to connect android emulator to the internet - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2039964) [Disabling the LAN card](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2702663) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to connect your computer to wifi and then the emulator will use your computer's wifi connection. The AVD is just an emulation of an android device. The AVD uses your computer's hardware to simulate the hardware of a real device the best that it can.

The AVD will also be 'connected to 3G/4G' if you are connected through Ethernet.

Edit:

When I tried this myself on my own editor, it appears that you can't enable wifi on the emulator, it will always be set to '3G' or '4G'. If you want to enable Wifi for development purposes, you should just use a real device. There is no way to enable wifi on the android emulator. This question has been asked on StackOverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator

Comment: when you put some thought to it, you can't really have wi-fi on an AVD, for wi-fi to actually work you need some hardware that accepts and transforms open air radio-waves to digital data. not something you can emulate.
either just settle for plain data transfer or use a physical device.